# ckeditor5 - custom container element - recursion error on paste

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm trying to create a CKEditor5 custom element plugin - mainly for custom format/styles -- nested divs etc.  Managed to be able to inject/format the elements, and I can type in them.  But if I try to copy and paste text into a custom element I get a too much recursion error.

MyWidget plugin:

```
export default class MyWidgetPlugin extends Plugin {

  init() {

    const editor = this.editor;

    editor.model.schema.register('my-widget', {
      inheritAllFrom: '$root',
      isLimit: true,
    });

    editor.conversion.elementToElement({ model: 'my-widget', view: 'my-widget' });
    editor.commands.add('myWidget', new MyWidgetCommand(editor));

  }

}
```

MyWidget command:

```
class MyWidgetCommand extends Command {

  execute() {

    const editor = this.editor;
    const block = first(this.editor.model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks());

    this.editor.model.change(writer => {

      const myWidget = writer.createElement('my-widget')
      writer.insert ( myWidget, block, 'after');
      writer.appendElement( 'paragraph', myWidget );

    });

  }

}
```

Inserting a widget injects this into the editor:

```
<my-widget>
  <p></p>
</my-widget>
```

And I can type fine, but I can't paste.  I'm guessing I got the schema wrong... have played around with quite a few different options.. but to no avail.

[image: console in chrome]

Comment: Have you tried with a regular html tag ? See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081759/copy-paste-custom-tags-in-ckeditor-4-0. It's the previous version but it seems CkEditor may have trouble with custom tags

Comment: @Bertrand Yes, I also tried `<div class="my-widget"><p></p></div>` - same result.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Maybe, you should post an issue : https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check it but I think that the issue is here:

```
editor.model.schema.register('my-widget', {
  inheritAllFrom: '$root',
  isLimit: true,
});
```

This schema rule says that `<my-widget>` will allow e.g. a `<paragraph>` inside it. But it doesn't say anything about where `<my-widget>` may be used. That's because `$root` is not allowed in any other element (cause it's a root :)).

I think that the following should work fine:

```
editor.model.schema.register('my-widget', {
  inheritAllFrom: '$root',
  allowIn: '$root',
  isLimit: true,
});
```

Alternatively, a more generic solution should work too:

```
editor.model.schema.register('my-widget', {
  inheritAllFrom: '$root',
  allowWhere: '$block',
  isLimit: true,
});
```

Still, the editor should not crash with an infinite loop, so I reported https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/issues/1441.

Comment: Great! That did it.  Thanks!